# Any useful personality mode for a RobCo unit?

Tags: fallout-4

You can find terminals where you can activate RobCo unit(s) with a selected personality mode.

Are there any useful or practical?

Because i ended up with another enemy when i protected myself from raiders and the bot with Law Enforcement saw that...

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can be useful. Construction Worker Mode attacks people not wearing hard hats.

Law enforcement mode attacks people with their weapons drawn so if you holster yours it should leave you alone.

The subway Stewart is bugged so it is almost impossible to give the token over you have a window of less then a second.

The medical one is mostly passive it wont actually heal you but is harmless as long as you leave it alone it will go up and shock hostiles though. That is about all I can think of regarding them